# How to make org show all properties as default?

Tags: org-mode

I want to show all properties of all subtrees while folding all of them is the default option but I can't find a option to this.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include an example to better describe what it is that you seek, and/or edit the wording of the question.  You say you "want to show all properties of all subtrees", but then you use the words "while folding all of them" which is the exact opposite showing them.  See also the section of the manual "**2.3.2 Initial visibility**":  http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the the `outline-*` set of commands may accomplish what you are looking for.  They do not consider property drawers when unfolding an outline.  In fact, `C-u C-u C-u TAB` in org-mode (`org-cycle`) actually calls `outline-show-all`.  If you don't want property drawers to be collapsed when folding headings you could bind TAB to `outline-toggle-children` instead of `org-cycle`.

Answer (score 0):

Old post I know, but if someone is interested check [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html) section 7: Properties and columns

Comment: Can you add a link to the specific part of the manual and a relevant quote?

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said. Otherwise this answer risks being deleted as a link-only answer. If that happens you might want to add your link as a comment on the question.